# Pass arguments to a method called by WCF Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, linq-to-sql

I'm really sorry if I sound stupid by this question, I'm new to WCF and I want to know if I can pass a Textbox value from a page to a WCF method.

**Here is my method called by the service in the Service.svn.cs file:**

```
public List<Product> GetProducts(string name)
{
  ProductDataClassDataContext db = new ProductDataClassDataContext();
  var products = db.usp_Get_Products();
  return products.ToList();
}
```

**And Here's the code file About.xaml.cs where the service is called**

```
private void OnSearchProductClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ServiceReference1.Service1Client webService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
  webService.GetProductsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetProductsCompletedEventArgs>(webService_GetProductsCompleted);
  webService.GetProductsAsync();
  txtblcName.Text = txtName.Text;   //Send this as parameter to usp_Get_Products
}

public void webService_GetProductsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetProductsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  ProductGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result; //Binding Datagrid 
}
```

I want to pass the `txtName` value to `GetProducts()` but seems like I can't do this since it gets called automatically. is there a way??

**Edited**

**Here is the Service Contract**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
  [OperationContract]
  List<Product> GetProducts(string name);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your service contract interface?

Comment: @Ahhhhbisto post edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your WCF ServiceContract contains only this OperationContract:

```
[OperationContract]
List<Product> GetProducts(string name);
```

Then your service call cannot compile, because string argument is missing.
To pass a TextBox value you should call it with this argument:

```
webService.GetProductsAsync(txtName.Text);
```

Make sure to "Update Service Reference" after any contract change.

Comment: I tried this but `public List<Product> GetProducts(string name)` gets `null` instead of the passed `txtName.text` value. Why is it so?

Comment: Worked after Updating Service Reference. Thank you for mentioning that :)